# JavaScript - conditional formatting within a tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip

I have a `tooltip` string builder line like this:

```
    scheduler.templates.tooltip_text = function(start,end,event)  
    {
        return "<strong style=\"font-size:16px;\"><a href=\"https://www.somewebsitethatshowsmoredetails.com/details:"+event.IMO+"/something:"+event.text+"\" target=\"_blank\">"+event.text+"</a></strong>"+" "+event.BubbleCode+
            "<ul><li><strong>.....and other html injection here"
    };
```

The tooltip, shows a URL link and some data fed from the `'event'` object.

One of those details is `'event.BubbleCode'`, which has one value at any one time, a numeric 0, 1, 2 or 3.

Is there a way to place an `switch()` statement or some logic within the string line above to turn that `BubbleCode` value into a colored character such as an asterisk?

Something like this...BUT for the '3' to be a GREEN asterisk, or if it's a value of '2' for it to be a RED asterisk.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a span and set its color.
If your "switch" should be inline just use an object and access it at event.BubbleCode.

It could look like this:

```js
    scheduler.templates.tooltip_text = function(start,end,event)  
    {
        return "<strong style=\"font-size:16px;\"><a href=\"https://www.somewebsitethatshowsmoredetails.com/details:"+event.IMO+"/something:"+event.text+"\" target=\"_blank\">"+event.text+"</a></strong><span style=\"color:" + {0:'black',1:'yellow',2:'red',3:'green'}[event.BubbleCode] + ";\">*</span>"+
            "<ul><li><strong>.....and other html injection here"
    };
```